# Bootstrap Modal CSS affected by web pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have created a browser extension that loads a bootstrap modal whose css is affected by the page visited hence makes it to appear as its not supposed to. I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Here is my bootstrap modal form;

```
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Ink To Board</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tag" class="control-label">Tag</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag">
              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="board" class="control-label">Board</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="board">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="desc" class="control-label">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="desc"></textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ink It</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Proof : check out [these images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gh6dfz4i5hcuiji/AAALEHPiCHZOceYyUExAvmYka?dl=0)

Comment: Which classes are being overridden?

Comment: Check these images https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gh6dfz4i5hcuiji/AAALEHPiCHZOceYyUExAvmYka?dl=0

Comment: You'll just have to make sure you don't use the same classes that bootstrap uses.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert, how do you mean? Do I pick the classes I need from bootstrap source file and load them as a css file for use? I think that may be messy...

Comment: No, you make sure that you don't use the same class names as Bootstrap unless you're doing it intentionally.